# iOS Ad Hoc installation fails on 2 specific devices

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an app that can be downloaded from a build server using ad hoc distribution. A client of mine is unable to install the app on their devices (an iPhone 8 and X respectively, both running iOS 12.2) however: The app does not receive the proper icon upon finishing the installation and cannot be launched. I cannot reproduce this as the app installs just fine on all of my devices (iPads and iPhones with varying iOS version).

I have checked multiple times and the client's UDIDs are added to the provisioning profile. I even went through the .ipa provisioning profile and checked the embedded.mobileprovision file and the UDIDs are all there.

Are there any other possible reasons that can cause an ad hoc installation to fail?

Comment: Have you considered using Test Flight? It makes distributing test versions of the app very simple.

Comment: you should try to install with iTunes manually and see if the issue exist then issue is with build otherwise it will be your server causing the issue.

Comment: TestFlight or Fabric is a good choice for Ad Hoc distribution. Try.

Answer (score 0):

- Solution 1: open System Prefrences -> Users & Groups -> Add a user account (build with new user is successfully
- Solution 2: open Keychain Access -> choose System, All Items -> delete certificate Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority

**If both of them don't work try following that is more likely with solution 2**

(1) Quit XCode and complete stop it.

(2) Open KeyChain Access and select "System".

(3) Delete Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority

(4) Close KeyChain Access.

(5) Start XCode and Clean project.

(6) Rebuild  app.

The problem is "on the Fly to installing".  Safari can not install the app. IOS devices shows a gray icon only.
It might be  that the instraller looks a differnet positon of the code sign in the ipa file.
iOS12 and iOS12.1 might check a code sign in the different location of ipa file comparing with iOS10 and iOS11.
Because with "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" in the Key Chain Access, the applicaiton can launch on
iOS10 and iOS11. And also, it is possible to install by safari.